# setter value is null

Tags: c#, nullable

I want to understand why after setting a double value in a setter, the value is null.

The code is like:

```
public Class Product
{
    private double? u_total;
    public double? Total
        {
            get
            {
                return u_total;
            }
            set 
            { 
              u_total = value;
             }
        }

}
```

when i call:

```
for (i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
{
   products.Total += list[i].Price !=null ? (double?)quantity*list[i].Price : 0;
}
```

for the first case, list[1].Price(double?) is a 1234.5 , but the value on the setter will be null.
And my produsts.Total 0.

Please advice what is wrong.

Comment: Simple regarding `Total`: you do `if (u_total != null) { return 0; }`. Got it?

Comment: You always return either `0` or `null`. I'm not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: if u_total == null at a guess..

Comment: yes, correct observation

Comment: i updated the code. same issue as mentioned. updated to a simple getter

Comment: is the format wrong? how to handle it?

Answer (score 4):

I guess instead of

```
if (u_total != null)
```

it should be

```
if (u_total == null)
```